# Use std::views::all or std::views::reverse conditionally at runtime

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I am trying to use conditionally one or other type of view based on boolean only known at runtime.

Issue here is that `std::views::reverse` result type is different from the result of `std::views::all`, so ternary operator can not work.
I have also tried `std::reverse` of `std::reverse`  hoping that and `std::views::all` will be compatible, but it also does not work.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>


void print_ascending(const std::vector<int>& sorted_data, const bool data_descending) { 
    // does not work
    //auto sorted_asc = data_descending ? std::views::reverse(sorted_data) : std::views::all(sorted_data);
    auto sorted_asc = sorted_data;
    if (data_descending) {
        std::ranges::reverse(sorted_asc);
    }
    fmt::print("{}\n", sorted_asc);
}

int main() {
    print_ascending({1,2,4}, false);
    print_ascending({8,7,4,2}, true);
}
```

notes:

- boolean is only known at runtime so I can not make it compile time argument
- I know I could probably do this with indexes or with if else (and then use .begin() and .end() or .rbegin() and .rend()), but I am looking for elegant ranges solution
- I know many views inherit from common base type, but that type is CRTP base class, so I guess I can not use that base class pointer as you would do normally with 2 classes that derive from same base

Comment: Passing in a Boolean value to make a function have two different behaviors is a code smell. Write two functions.

Comment: @康桓瑋 no, but my question is a duplicate of that one :)  I guess no good solutions :/

Comment: It's pretty easy to "visit" a boolean value to compile time ("`if (runtime_boolean) f<true>(); else f<false>()`", you see the same things in implementations of `std::visit` for the index of a variant, just with more possible values), which you can apply to your problem like this: https://godbolt.org/z/q78Przo6n